# How does request pass through filter even though servlet mapping is not present?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have web.xml which contains just a filter, Which maps to a specific URL pattern.
If I give a url which matches the pattern. It goes through the filter comes back and gives 404 status. I understand that this is because the there is no resource mapped in web.xml. Why would it go through the filter?

Can I keep a wrapper around filter response and modify the response to a meaningful one instead of giving 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that there is nothing behind your filter, and you want to make all the work in your filter alone, you just don't need to call `chain.doFilter()`.

Example:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.getWriter().println("Nothing passes further!");
    response.getWriter().flush();
}
```